# Twilio using Gather to get UserID and Password

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-twiml

Currently, I'm testing out features of Twilio. I simply wanted to get two numbers from the user representing a username and password. What happens is because I don’t know what address to put in action, it defaults to the same time and loops the first gather over and over again. Currently, I’m using Spark and ngrok to test my code.

```java
package com.example;
import com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;
import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Gather;
import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Say;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        post("/", (request, response) -> {
            Say say  = new Say.Builder(
                    "Enter UserID.")
                    .build();
            Gather gather = new Gather.Builder().action("/").say(say).build();
            Say say2  = new Say.Builder(
                    "Enter Password.")
                    .build();
            Gather gather2 = new Gather.Builder().action("/").say(say2).build();        
            VoiceResponse voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                    .gather(gather)
                    .gather(gather2)
                    .build();
                          
            return voiceResponse.toXml();

        });

    }
}
```

I tried changing the action attribute to a random address like /test, I changed the method to POST or GET, but neither seemed to have any effect except in the ngrok dashboard. The problem I'm currently having is I have no clue how to use Spark and the Gather verb together.

Answer (score 0):

It repeats the actions over and over again because of the properties of the gather TwiMl element.

First, you should point to a different endpoint of your application and handle the response at this endpoint. Once you parse the user input at this endpoint, you can return another TwiML [response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) that asks for the second input, which you then need to process at a third endpoint.

With this in mind, I see a second problem with the code above. You ask for both inputs sequentially, meaning you only ask for the second input if the caller ignores the first prompt and remains quiet. Look at "Scenario 1-3" of [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#action) for more details.

I understand that implementing so many endpoints for a simple IVR might be confusing at first. The good news is that this can be much simpler by using [Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-build-an-ivr).